# React Native - Data Grid

Tags: javascript, react-native, datagridview, datagrid

I'm working on a business application for Android/iOS where the users can create invoices by adding articles into a table/data grid. I'm working with React Native and am looking for an appropriate component. The requirements are adding/deleting rows und changing cells.

I tried a few components but they didn't fit my needs.

Do you have any recommendation for a data grid under React Native?

Answer (score 0):

The best choice for your needs is using the `FlatList` component. It is recommended by `react-native` team and its performance is good (see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html)). `FlatList` is also so easy to use and you can read a useful document of it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/flatlist.html). A simple example of `FlatList` would be like this:

```
  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

  _renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <MyListItem
      id={item.id}
      title={item.title}
    />
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        extraData={this.state}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
      />
    );
  }
```

You can add or remove an item from the input list of `FlatList` (in this example `this.state.data`) simply and by passing the `this.state` value to the `extraData` prop, the `FlatList` will be aware of your state changes and will be updated automatically with the best performance.